# How can I upload a Zipfile to my Application Server using an Applet

Tags: web-services, file-upload, jakarta-ee, applet, application-server

I use an applet to bundle some files into a zip and during that I create a description-object.
I already utilize JavaEE Webservices to send the description-object to the server but how do I transport my zip?

I'm fairly new to Java EE and want to know if there is a common way to do that already (since java ee offers a lot) or would I use something ordinary like ftp?

I imagine something like a takeFileWebService that I can use from my applet, which then calls some Method onFileReceived on the serverside to handle the file, dunno :/

Thank in advance,
philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using kind of an uncommon, maybe even insecure way now. Since I need to send a describing Object anyway I just appended my file as an array of bytes.

I lookup my TakeStuffEJB via JNDI, and then I'll invoke a remote-method that wants a byte[] as parameter. I do CRC32 integrity checks on client and server side and it works. There is a limit to filesize though. Files above 20 MB whill throw a MarshalException("Not Completed") after a while.

Maybe this is insane because I don't think RMI was designed for filetransfers. But I'll give it a try since the files I'm sending a rarely larger than 1 MB.

Comment: I further improved this with a Stateful Session Bean. With 3 Methods,

  `initNewFileTransfer(FileNameAndInfo)`
  `writeChunk(byte[] data, int NumberOfBytes)`
  `finishFileTransfer(long checksum)`

I secure the order of the methodcalls with a StateEnum and in `@PrePassivate` i can reset states and free resources.
This way I can do a buffered transfer through RMI with any size.